# Plotting the normal vector of a plane in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera, linear-algebra, pose-estimation

I'm using a 2D barcode to identify a plane in 3D space and I want to plot its normal with respect to its center.

This is the code I'm using to compute the normal

```
def compute_normal(camera, board, bounds, frame):
    extrinsics, ip, op = get_extrinsics(camera, frame, board, bounds)
    extrinsic = extrinsics[0]

    if not extrinsic: return [], None

    camera_transform = M_from_extrinsic(extrinsic)
    transformed_board = transform_board(board, camera_transform)

    # change this to be the corners of any board, not just 4-square

    p1 = transformed_board[3][:3]
    p2 = transformed_board[6][:3]
    p3 = transformed_board[8][:3]

    l1 = p2 - p1
    l2 = p3 - p1

    normal = np.cross(l1, l2)

    return normal, extrinsic
```

`board` is simply a 3xN array of object points (everything is backed by solvePnP). The points p1, p2, p3 are the top left, top right, and bottom left of an ideal calibration board. The circled points are the ones I am choosing for my computation. The other points are more corners which are not being considered for this particular question.

[image]

After I compute the normal, this is how I plot it.

```
normal, extrinsic = compute_normal(camera0, board0, [[0, 4]], im)

if len(normal):

    projected_center, jac0 = cv2.projectPoints(board_center, extrinsic.rvec, extrinsic.tvec, camera0.mtx, camera0.dist)
    projected_norm, jac1 = cv2.projectPoints(np.array([normal]), extrinsic.rvec, extrinsic.tvec, camera0.mtx, camera0.dist)

    origin = clean_image_points(projected_center.reshape(1, 2))[0]
    vec = clean_image_points(projected_norm.reshape(1, 2))[0]

    cv2.arrowedLine(im, origin, vec, (0, 255, 0), 5)
```

However, I'm getting a result that looks like this

[image]

As you can see, the green line is pointing in some direction where it should be pointing towards the screen, since the board is facing the camera more or less head on.

I can confirm that calculating the extrinsics is working fine since I am using it in several other places. I'm just not sure about the normal computation and the plotting.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48882152/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/88757/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer per se, but can you stream the output live for your own debugging? You might notice something like that the arrow moves left when you turn right (x axis negated) or that it seems to be mirrored along the diagonal (y and x values switched).

Comment: Yeah I think I’ll give this a shot soon. Only problem is that it’s a 4K feed and my laptop isn’t that fast.

Comment: Try downsizing via 2x pyrDown's or resize before the imshow.

Answer (score 0):

I think the second 3d point you want to project is `board_center + normal` (or minus depending where the normal is pointing to). Projecting the normal alone will not be helpful as it is just a unit vector representing a direction.